# angular2 ngrx, error while deploying to github-pages

Tags: angular, deployment, github-pages, ngrx

I added reducers to my angular2 project like this:

```
const rootReducer = compose(storeLogger(), combineReducers)({
  toolbar: toolbarReducer
});

  imports: [
    ...,
    StoreModule.provideStore(rootReducer)
  ],
```

It's working correctly, but when I try to deploy it to github-pages

```
ng github-pages:deploy
```

Then I end up with the following error:

```
ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 12:42 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol compose in /Users/gkucmierz/learn/coin-tools/node_modules/@ngrx/core/compose.d.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /Users/gkucmierz/learn/coin-tools/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /Users/gkucmierz/learn/coin-tools/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /Users/gkucmierz/learn/coin-tools/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /Users/gkucmierz/learn/coin-tools/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /Users/gkucmierz/learn/coin-tools/src/app/app.module.ts
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear.
You have to make your code statically analyzable for AoT.

See here:
https://medium.com/@isaacplmann/making-your-angular-2-library-statically-analyzable-for-aot-e1c6f3ebedd5#.3ipjxwp1z

This error has nothing to do with github pages.

This builds your code in JIT mode: `ng build`
And this in AOT mode: `ng build --aot`
The `github-pages:deploy` command was doing AOT builds.